# react: передача из функционального компонента несколько состояний вовне

Tags: reactjs, state, useeffect, usestate

есть функциональный компонент (отображающий некоторые элементы управления), принимающий на вход два параметра `param1`, `param2` и колбэк `onChange`, по которому возвращаются обновлённые параметры.

если передачу параметров делать сразу после изменения параметров:

```js
[param1, setParam1] = useState(props.param1)
[param2, setParam2] = useState(props.param2)

const handleChangeParam1 = (newParam) => {
    setParam1(newParam);
    props.onChange({
        param1: param1, 
        param2: param2
    });
}
```

то в `onChange` передаётся старый `param1`, что понятно, поскольку `setParam1` не гарантирует изменение `param1` сразу.

**Каким образом тогда можно добиться того, чтоб по `onChange` всегда передавались ТОЛЬКО актуальные параметры?**

конечно можно использовать `newParam`, получаемый в колбэке:

```js
const handleChangeParam1 = (newParam) => {
    setParam1(newParam);
    props.onChange({
        param1: newParam, 
        param2: param2
    });
}
```

но когда передаваемых состояний много, то для каждого изменения состояния писать такой код - не очень универсальное решение :(

Если же использовать `useEffect`:

```js
const handleChangeParam1 = (newParam) => {
    setParam1(newParam);
}

useEffect(() => {
    props.onChange({
        param1: newParam, 
        param2: param2
    });
}, [props, param1, param2]);
```

то всё работает, все универсально, но возникает ошибка многократного вызова:

> Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a
> component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either
> doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on
> every render.

**подскажите как корректно можно реализовать данный функционал и откуда берется эти многократные вызовы?**

понимаю, что похоже из-за цепочки
[новое значение] -> [установка состояния] -> [вызов эффекта] -> [передача данных вовне] -> [выставление из данных, переданных вовне пропсов для компонента] -> [установка состояния]...

но я думал, что вызов будет ровно 1, дальше Реакт поймёт, что значения (props) не менялись и не будет перерисовывать постоянно компоненты

Comment: Функция `handleChangeParam1` срабатывает на каждый рендер или по какому то пользовательскому событию?

Comment: Я уже разобрался - все из-за того, что передаю в `useEffect` `props`, поскольку сравнение происходит не по содержимому объектов в JS, то React кажется, что props постоянно меняется, поэтому идет перерисовка постоянная, как только я сделал локальную копию `props` как состояния `[localProps] = useState(props)`, то проблема исчезла